# Boost regex to c++ regex

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to move some boost code to standard c++ code. Everything seems to work correctly except the regex.
I've seen online that c++ regex are not working correctly sometimes. However I have this code:

```
std::string tRegex = ".{0.7}";
std::regex regex1("\.{[0-9],[0-9]}[A-Z]*|[A-Z]+");
std::regex regex2("[A-Z]*\.{[0-9],[0-9]}|[A-Z]+");
std::sregex_token_iterator titer(tRegex.begin(), tRegex.end(), regex1, 0);
```

And I receive this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  Unexpected character in brace expression.
```

But honestly I don't understand what is the unexpected character..

Comment: Braces have a special meaning in regex. If you want literal braces you need to escape them.

Comment: Backslash is an escape character in qouted string literals. Thus, if you want to have a backslash in the regular expression, you have to either escape it, by writing it double, or use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), i.e. `R"(\)"`.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that escaping the brace \{ fix the error. however the reg ex doesn't work with boost syntax. And honestly I don't understand why.
I can't use R because the size exceed 16 characters.

Comment: _"I can't use R because the size exceed 16 characters."_ — Raw string literals do not have a size limit. This "16 characters" limit is only for the optional delimiter sequence, for example, the regular string literal `"Hello"` can be expressed as raw string literal `R"blah(Hello)blah"`, where `blah` is the custom delimiter sequence. But this is really needed only when your string contains the `)"` as a literal sequence in it (so that'd cause an error otherwise). In vast majority of cases, there is no need to use any delimiter sequence at all: for example, just `R"(Hello)"` will do.